# Mercurial --template "{latesttag}{latesttagdistance}" doesn't work

Tags: mercurial

I'm using "Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.1.2)" on my Ubuntu.
I'm new to mercurial, and just created a new project on sourceforge.net.
I added some code files, commited some changes, pulled & pushed.
I created some tags "0.1.1", "0.1.2" and "0.1.3" using "hg tag" and now I want to pack it all in a revision zip file.

A friend sent me a script that automatically picks a name and create the zip file using

```
hg parent --template "{node|short}\n{latesttag}\n{latesttagdistance}"
```

I executed this command but the *{latesttag}* & *{latesttagdistance}* doesn't seem to work. When I try:

```
hg log --template "{latesttag}{latesttagdistance}\n"
```

it just prints a bunch of empty lines.

Does anyone have any suggestions for why the templates don't work? Should I configure something in some hg configuration file? Does it have anything to do with the fact I don't use branches as I'm supposed to?

Any suggestions could help. I am new to mercurial so it's probably something basic that I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial 1.1 is quite old. `{latesttag}` and `{latesttagdistance}` are only available since [Mercurial 1.4](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#A1.4_.282009-11-16.29). If you don't want to update Ubuntu (Ubuntu 10.10 comes with Mercurial 1.6), you can use a [PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/stable-snapshots).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Ubuntu-derivative, you can install the newest version from launchpad:
https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases